# how to call bold function in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to change the font properties(bold or italic) in the Textarea. Below I have placed my code for your reference. Please let me know how to call bold properties in my script.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='myNoteApp' ng-controller='noteController'>
    <p>
        <textarea ng-model='message' cols='50' rows='10'></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button ng-click='save()'>Save</button>
        <button ng-click='clear()'>Clear</button>
        <button ng-click='bold()'>Bold</button>
    </p>
    <p>Numbers of characters left: <span ng-bind='left()'></span></p>
</div>
```

myNoteApp JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myNoteApp', []);
```

myNoteCtrl JS:

```
app.controller('noteController', function($scope){
    $scope.message='';
    $scope.save=function(){alert('Saved!');};
    $scope.clear=function(){$scope.message='';};
    $scope.left=function(){return 300-$scope.message.length;};
    $scope.bold=function(){return $scope.bold;};
});
```

Comment: I can't understand what you exactly want to do

Comment: $scope.bold=function(){return $scope.bold;}; Are U serious? Returning the  same reference of called function?

Comment: I want to change the font weight(bold) while I going to click the bold button.

Comment: @ajai why don't you try `ng-class` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to change your text to bold or italic when you click on a button ? If that's the case please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Aejvm/43/) and your example of html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="text" class="{{class}}" ng-model="rootFolders" ng-  init="rootFolders='Bob'" >
<button ng-click="chiliSpicy()">bold</button>
<button ng-click="jalapenoSpicy()">italic</button>
<br>rootFolders={{rootFolders}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) will help you.

You need some like this:

```
<textarea class="textarea" ng-class="{ 'im_bold' : bold }"></textarea>
<button type="button" ng-click=" bold = !bold; "></button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.bold = false;
```

CSS:

```
.textarea {
   font-style: italic;
}

.im_bold {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

See at [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dD2FVKl74ykimhnGWQ4B?p=preview).

Comment: Please suggest class properties as well. Jai Balaji :)

Comment: @ajai what moments didn't clear in the code from above?

Comment: Yeah, I found the issue where I made. Thank you.